# Are there any libraries (or frameworks) that aid in implementing the server side of ODBC?

Tags: python, odbc

I'd like to add a feature to my behind the firewall webapp that exposes and ODBC interface so users can connect with a spreadsheet program to explore our data.

We don't use a RDBMS so I want to emulate the server side of the connection.

I've searched extensively for a library or framework that helps to implement the server side component of an ODBC connection with no luck.  Everything I can find is for the other side of the equation - connecting one's client program to a database using an ODBC driver.

It would be great to use Python but at this point language preference is secondary, although it does have to run on *nix.

Answer (score 0):

The server side of ODBC is already done, it is your RDBMS.

ODBC is a client side thing, most implementations are just a bridge between ODBC interface and the native client interface for you-name-your-RDBMS-here.

That is why you will not find anything about the server side of ODBC... :-)

Implementing a RDBMS (even with a subset of SQL) is no easy quest. My advice is to expose your underlying database storage, the best solution depends on what database are you using.

If its a read-only interface, expose a database mirror using some sort of asynchronous replication.

If you want it read/write, trust me, you better don't. If your customer is savvy, expose an API, it he isn't you don't want him fiddling with your database. :-)

[updated]

If your data is not stored on a RDBMS, IMHO there is no point in exposing it through a relational interface like ODBC. The advice to use some sort of asynchronous replication with a relational database is still valid and probably the easiest approach.

Otherwise you will have to reinvent the wheel implementing an SQL parser, network connection, authentication and related logic. If you think it's worth, go for it!

Comment: I know that's the way ODBC is meant to be used in it's traditional sense.  I want to emulate the database part of the server side of the ODBC connection and expose it to users.  My data is not in a RDBMS.

Comment: Exactly.  Hence the quest for a library or framework :-)

It is worth it to explore the data using common desktop tools like a spreadsheet.  It's not worth it to start from scratch.  My users are analysts.  They **love** spreadsheets.  Read only is expected.

Comment: @pykid: they would be happy with a 'Download as Excel' button in your webapp interface. The xlwt library is nice for this, you can export a workbook with many worksheets but you are limited to 256 columns and 65,536 rows per worksheet.